# How would I write a function in Dr. Racket which consumes a list of list of integers and produces a new list of list of integers?

Tags: racket, higher-order-functions

How would I write a function in Dr. Racket which consumes a list of list of integers and produces a new list of list of integers with a transformation (sqr) applied to each element.
Note: There is an equal number of elements in each list.

Here are two examples to show what I am saying:

Example 1:

```
(list (list 1 2) (list 3 -2))
```

Should produce:

```
(list (list 1 4) (list 9 4))
```

Example 2:

```
(list (list 3 4 5) (list 2 1 3) (list 2 3 7) (list 0 -3 2))
```

Should produce:

```
(list (list 9 16 25) (list 4 1 9) (list 4 9 49) (list 0 9 4))
```

Here is my code so far:

```
(define (transform-to-sqr b)
  (map sqr b))
```

If I type in:

```
(transform-to-sqr (list (list 1 2) (list 3 -2)))
```

I get an error message saying:
sqr: expected a number; given (list 1 2).

Why is this happening. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` higher-order procedure applies a procedure over the *elements* of a list, but in this case the elements are lists themselves. To operate on the nested elements, we need to nest calls to `map`:

```
(define (transform-to-sqr matrix)
  (map (λ (row) (map sqr row))
       matrix))
```

It works as expected:

```
(transform-to-sqr '((1 2) (3 -2)))
=> '((1 4) (9 4))

(transform-to-sqr '((3 4 5) (2 1 3) (2 3 7) (0 -3 2)))
=> '((9 16 25) (4 1 9) (4 9 49) (0 9 4))
```